# Can't upload xlsx library in Amazon Web Service (R)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, xlsx

I need to use the xlsx package in AWS but I have not been able to upload it. I have tried, as other posts suggested, installing the package with its dependencies, but didn't work. This is the error message that I get using AWS:
[image]

When I try to upload the library in my computer (without using AWS), I can upload the library without problem. Does anybody knows what could be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Installation of packages with a Java dependency is notoriously troublesome, unfortunately. If you don't need to write to xlsx, perhaps package `readxl` would do instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, I need to. I need to export multiple dataframes to an existing excel file, so I need write.xlsx to use its append = TRUE function.  I believe that I can't do this with other functions such as write_xlsx