# Exporting dataframe to an existing excel without using xlsx package R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, xlsx

I need to export multiple dataframes to an existing excel file. I'm working in AWS and as stated in this post [Can't upload xlsx library in Amazon Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468082/cant-upload-xlsx-library-in-amazon-web-service-r?noredirect=1#comment131457650_74468082), I can't use write.xlsx from the xlsx package.

Similar functions such as write_xlsx do not have the append function that allows me to export the dataframes in the existing file without overwriting it. Which function could be a substitute for write.xlsx? Thanks in advance! (Sorry for not providing any reproducible example, I didn't come up with any for this particular problem)

Comment: XLConnect package may be useful for you

Comment: There is a [writexl package](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-writing-excel-files-with-r-using-readxl-and-writexl/) which doesn't depend on Java.